# iPhone X TableView Footer problems

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

Ok, two things first: I'm still new to iOS development and I bet this question was already answered a few times, so feel free to link it to a working solution

Now to the problem: I have a **UITableViewController** including **custom footer views**. (They are custom to add a little border on the bottom, the build-in footer is just plain grey). Everything looks ok for the old school iPhones, however on the new X ones I get the following:

[image: Footer is broken]

Is there a way to extend the footer view all down to the bottom of the view area?

Comment: You are  just in need of set bottom constraint to safeArea of bottom layout guide.

Answer (score 2):

The default layout is like this because of safe area. If you want to let the footer view cover the content I can give you 2 solutions.

- Use `UITableViewStyleGrouped` instead, but the footer view will not static on the screen.
- I don't think this is the best practise, but I think the layout should be you are looking for. This is a little bit tricky. The step is:

  1. Create an extend view that the height **equal to the bottom safe area**.
  2. Put this extend view below the footer view and set the background color same as header view's background color.
  3. Make sure the **header view** height **equals to the bottom safe area height**. (This step is the tricky point)

---

Sample code

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UILabel *footerView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.968 green:0.968 blue:0.968 alpha:1]; //Section Header Background Color
    footerView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    footerView.text = @"Footer";

    UIView *extendView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    extendView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    extendView.backgroundColor = footerView.backgroundColor;
    [footerView addSubview:extendView];

    [footerView addConstraints:@[
                                 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:extendView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:footerView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0],
                                 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:extendView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:footerView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0],
                                 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:extendView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:footerView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0],
                                 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:extendView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:footerView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom]
                                 ]];
    return footerView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
}
```

**Screen Record GIF**

[image: Image TableView]

Comment: Hey SerKo, thank you! Works perfectly. However do you know why the view must be an UILabel? Changing it to a UITableViewHeaderFooterView does result in the same issue again. I guess the standard UITableViewHeaderFooterView has some kind of height constraint, right?

Comment: It can be any UIView, i think you should implement the height of the footer / header view.